# Jest says TypeError: (0 , ClassName.functionName) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a js file as follows

```
import axios from "axios";

export default class SomeService {

  static getSomething(id) {
    return axios
        .get(API_BASE_URL + API_URL_Something, {
        params: { id: id},
      })
      .then((result) => {
        return result.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  }
}
```

And I have a test.js using jest as follows

```
import axios from "axios";

import { getSomething } from "../SomeService.js";

jest.mock("axios");

describe("getSomething", () => {
    describe("when API call is successful", () => {
        it("should return some details", () => {
            // given
            const someDetails = [
                { id: 1, name: "Something 1" },
                { id: 2, name: "Something 2" },
            ];
            axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(someDetails);
            // when
            const result = getSomething(123); // ERROR THROWN HERE

            // then
            let url = API_BASE_URL + Constants.API_URL_Something;
            expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`${url}`);
            expect(result).toEqual(someDetails);
        });
    });

    describe("when API call fails", () => {
        it("should return empty entity details", () => {
            // ...
        });
    });
});
```

But when I run npm test I get this error

```
TypeError: (0 , _SomeService.getSomething) is not a function
```

I have tried making the function non static (I shouldn't have to), tried exporting it (couldn't get the syntax right perhaps), but can't get it to quite work. Other similar posts do not solve my issue either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code you are exporting the class `SomeService`, not its internal `getSomething` method. So surely you need to change your test code to something like the following:

```js
import axios from "axios";

import { getSomething } from "../SomeService.js";

jest.mock("axios");

describe("getSomething", () => {
    describe("when API call is successful", () => {
        it("should return some details", () => {
            //...
            // when
            const service = new SomeService();
            const result = service.getSomething(123);

            // ...
```

Comment: Because it's a static function, I tried doing SomeService.getSomething(123) but I got "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSomething'). I then tried what you said and it says " TypeError: _EntityDetailService.EntityDetailService is not a constructor".